# Close button X not removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm using jqueryui dialog, I want to hide the X button there at the top.

I tried the code below, but it didn't work.

> $( '.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').remove();

My JS:

```
 $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            closeOnEscape: false,
            ...
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Confirmation Message" class="dialogboxstart">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="dialogRow">
            <span class="dialogHeading" id="confirmMsg"></span>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Make  a JS fiddle demonstrating your problem

Comment: did u use the remove after document ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing that in the `open` function of dialog.

JS:

```
    $(function () {        
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            open: function () {
                $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').remove(); //Remove here.
            }
        });
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/459/

Comment: @AbdulMoiz Make sure that it doesn't remove other dialog's icon. You need to be more specific in the  selector

Answer (score 1):

You probably need this

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the remove in document.ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( '.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').remove();
});
```

[***Here***](http://jsfiddle.net/g4rhdrmz/2/) is the fiddle.